# Eclipse Juno missing localVariable color

Tags: eclipse

I installed juno the other day, and then the color theme plugin, and chose zenburn as the theme.
I noticed one annoying difference over indigo:
In Javascript, the local variables are not getting localVariable or localVariableDeclaration color applied, which is one of my favorite features

[image: this is indigo where local var x is colored differently than global var y]

[image: this is juno where local var x is colored white like y :(]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to "fix" it

went to

Preferences > JavaScript > Editor > Syntax Coloring

Even though in the element Local variable declarations and references where set enabled here, disabling and then enabling them and hitting apply fixed it for me.

Comment: It still happens after restarting eclipse or applying a different theme, repeating this fixes it again, very annoying